# Callback after my tabs jquery ui create

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I `init` jquery `ui tabs` like so:

```
$.ui.tabs( null,  $("#tabs")  );
```

How to initialize callback after creating my `tabs`?

Comment: jquery ui tabs has this Events: 
activate
beforeActivate
beforeLoad create load
i pretty sure, that one of them can solve ur problem

Comment: Instead of `null` you can pass any options you want, or use the `.tabs("option")` function afterwards. As for event handlers, you bind them with `.on()`, same as all other jquery events. Can you add more detail about what you're trying to do? The question as it is is *very* unclear

Answer (score 1):

First way syntax:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  load: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Try, it helped, 
second way syntax

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "tabsload", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Or, if you need exactly on create:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  create: function( event, ui ) {}
});

$( ".selector" ).on( "tabscreate", function( event, ui ) {} );
```